# How in the world do I get this div in front

Tags: html, css, wordpress

my website zaczess.se/v2/

The menu cart, when you open it it gets behind some widgets like the instagram posts and also reviews. I have tried putting z-index on all kinds of divs now but it is not working.

Any tips?[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkQht.jpg)

```
.elementor-menu-cart__main {
z-index: 500;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 350px;
```

Comment: Please share with us the code example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's hard for me to reproduce the problem since I don't know where the problem is. It's a website built in wordpress so I haven't done any coding more than the CSS part.

Comment: Remove `z-index: 1;` from `#sb_instagram #sbi_images.sbi_carousel` and `.swiper-wrapper`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-d1db9ee.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default {
    z-index: 0 !important;
}

section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-b9a071e.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default {
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

This should help. The codes sets the sections below the cart menu